# Qual è il significato di "imbastire" in questa frase? E qual è il soggetto e il complemento oggetto del verbo "imbastire" nella frase?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, grammatical-analysis

Leggendo la frase seguente nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, mi sono venuti due dubbi:

> Per insidia che *imbastisse* la persuasione d'esser sospettata e giudicata male, Artemisia non poté, questa volta, che rispecchiarsi innocente.

Il primo dubbio è sul significato di "imbastire" in questa frase. Ho cercato questo vocabolo in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che i significati figurati sono ideare la linea d'azione o la trama di qualcosa. Tuttavia, non capisco il senso di questo verbo nel brano precedente.

Il secondo dubbio è quale sia il soggetto e quale il complemento oggetto del verbo "imbastire", aspetto che è necessario chiarire per poter capire la frase. Secondo me, il soggetto è "la persuasione d'esser sospettata e giudicata male" e il complemento oggetto è la "insidia".
Cioè, la frase afferma che "la persuasione d'esser sospettata e giudicata male" imbastiva la "insidia". Tuttavia, nei commenti a una risposta a questa domanda si è affermato che non è così, che "la persuasione d'esser sospettata e giudicata male" sarebbe il complemento oggetto di "imbastire": si imbastiva la persuasione.

Ho pensato che questa frase è come quando, ad esempio, si dice

> Il pane che compro io ...

Quello che compro è "il pane" (complemento oggetto), ed "io" è il soggetto di "compro" che si scrive dopo il verbo per dargli più enfasi. Cioè, "io compro il pane". Nello stesso modo, nella frase del romanzo, "insidia" è il complemento oggetto e "la persuasione d'esser sospettata e giudicata male" è il soggetto del verbo "imbastire", scritto dopo il verbo per maggiore enfasi.

Ho cercato di scrivere io stessa una frase ancor più simile a quella del testo, che penso sia venuta fuori un po' forzata:

> Per molti soldi che guadagnasse addesso Filippo, non poté pagare tutti i suoi debiti.

Questa frase afferma che "Filippo guadagnava molti soldi", cioè "Filippo" è il soggetto del verbo "guadagnare" e invece "molti soldi" è il complemento oggetto.

Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi e così poter finalmente capire il significato della frase?

Comment: chi è il soggetto? La frase precedente a questa quale è?

Comment: @mario: Nella frase precedente si spiega che il padre di Artemisia, il pittore Orazio Gentileschi, arriva a casa all'improvviso a un'ora inconsueta e trova la figlia lavorando, cioè dipingendo.

Comment: ma chi imbastisce, il padre, o la figlia? Nel primo caso, forse si voleva dire qualcosa "per paura che il padre si convincesse che c'era motivo di sospettarla,  A. dovette dichiararsi innocente".  Non ha molto senso che A. stessa imbastisse, anche se questo viene suggerito dall'espressione 'd'esser sospettata' (invece che 'di sospettarla'). Non so chi sia Anna Banti, ma forse questa frase le è venuta male.

Comment: @mario: Penso che il soggetto del verbo "imbastire" non è il padre né la figlia, ma la "persuasione d'esser sospettata e giudicata male". Comunque, penso che sia Artemisia quella che è persuasa "d'esser sospettata e giudicata male".

Comment: @mario: [Anna Banti](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Banti), pseudonimo di Lucia Lopresti, è stata una scrittrice molto cólta.  Non penso che la frase le sia venuta male, è semplicemente che aveva un stile molto ricercato ma, allo stesso tempo, molto ricco, poetico e di una grande bellezza.

Comment: @mario: Secondo me, la frase afferma che "la persuasione d'esser sospettata e giudicata male" che aveva Artemisia imbastiva la insidia.

Comment: forse si può leggere: per paura di predisporre le condizioni (da parte di A. stessa) per cui si potesse formare (negli altri) la persuasione di esser sospettata (ma qui mi tornerebbe meglio 'di sospettarla'), allora A. si dichiarò innocente. Ma non mi convince.

Comment: Ho finalmente letto il brano su wikipedia. Il senso mi sembra sia che - vedendo l'allegria del padre - A. capisce che egli la considera innocente. La frase potrebbe quindi voler dire che nonostante (si pensi che) A. tendesse a pensarsi ("imbastisse la persuasione") sospettata, in questa occasione vede che è considerata innocente ("rispecchiarsi innocente"). Leggerei sulla falsariga di: "(benchè si creda / fosse anche) che per attitudine pensasse tutto il male di se stessa, questa volta si ammirò";  ovvero invertendo l'ordine  "per attitudine che pensasse tutto il male, questa volta si ammirò".

Answer (score 7):

L'[imbastitura](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punto_imbastitura) è un particolare tipo di punto da cucito che si usa per fissare i margini della stoffa prima della cucitura vera e propria.

In senso figurato si usa in frasi come *imbastire un discorso* proprio per dare il senso di preparativo, predisposizione pur non definitiva.

Nel testo *imbastire la persuasione d'esser sospettata* significa semplicemente che *il suo comportamento poteva portare a farla sospettare*.

Comment: A me, però, sembra che la frase dica che la persuasione d'esser sospettata e giudicata male imbastiva la insidia.

Comment: Forse, tenendo conto di quello che hai detto, significa che tale persuasione insinuava o preparava la insidia.

Comment: Penso che quello che hai scritto qui, mi abbia fatto capire il senso del brano, ma l'ultima frase della tua risposta non mi soddisfa. Secondo me, Artemisia ha il sospetto "d'esser sospettata e giudicata male". Questo la prepara, la predispone a subire insidia nel caso il suo sospetto si avverasse.

Comment: Ho provato a leggere il brano (che, fra l'altro, è ricopiato nella pagina di wikipedia da te suggerita), cominciando dalla frase precedente. A questo punto mi viene il dubbio che non sia *insidia* sostantivo ma *Insidia* personaggio mitologico. In questo modo si può rileggere la frase come: *Per quanto Insidia potesse tessere le sue trame persuadendola a sentirsi sospettabile o mal giudicabile, Artemisia si riconobbe innocente*. Di certo è uno stile molto convoluto e di difficile comprensione anche per il madrelingua.

Comment: Ma non credi che è semplicemente che la persuasione d'esser sospettata e giudicata male predisponeva Artemisia a aspettarsi un'insidia? Io adesso la frase la capisco in questo modo.

Comment: @charo Scritta in questo modo non ne riconosco il senso: dal testo sembra essere la presunzione ad essere imbastita, nella tua versione, invece, è l'insidia ad essere , in un certo senso, imbastita. Ma l'insidia non è qualcosa che ci si aspetta, non può essere  un rimprovero o una punizione da parte di Orazio, non è, normalmente, qualcosa che si attende (insidioso è qualcosa di strisciante, che ti colpisce alle spalle). Per queste ragioni non mi torna l'interpretare a tuo modo questa frase.

Comment: Ma è come quando, ad esempio, si dice "il pane che compro io ...", no? Quello che compro è il pane, ed "io" è il soggetto di "compro" che si scrive dopo il verbo per dargli più enfasi. Cioè, "io compro il pane". Nello stesso modo, in questa frase, "la persuasione d'esser sospettata e giudicata male imbastiva la insidia".

Comment: Una frase più simile a quella del brano: "Per molti soldi che guadagnasse addesso Filippo, non poté pagare tutti i suoi debiti" --> "Filippo guadagnava molti soldi".

Comment: Per parafrasare la tua ultima frase io la vedo come: *Per quanto Filippo potesse guadagnare, la banca gli pignorò comunque la casa*. Nella frase originale il *quanto* è omesso (per poetica o per arcaicità del testo), *Filippo* è *Insidia*, *potesse guadagnare* è *imbastisse la persuasione*, *Artemisia* è *la banca* e *si rispecchiò innocente* è *gli pignorò la casa*.

Comment: Forse questo aspetto (qual è il soggetto del verbo "imbastire" nella frase) meriterebbe un'altra domanda.

Comment: Non so se ne vale la pena... alla fine l'identificazione del soggetto è strettamente legata all'interpretazione del testo. Io modificherei questa stessa domanda per sottolineare l'indeterminazione rilevata.

Comment: Forse sì, hai ragione. Lo farò appena posso.

Answer (score 0):

Prima di tutto, vorrei ringraziare @N74: la sua risposta alla domanda mi ha fatto capire il senso di "imbastire" in questo contesto. Come ha detto @N74, in modo figurato questo verbo ha il significato di preparare, predisporre.

Tuttavia, la risposta di @N74 non chiarisce il mio secondo dubbio, cioè, quale sia il soggetto e quale il complemento oggetto del verbo "imbastire" nella frase citata. Come ho già spiegato nel testo della domanda, secondo me, il soggetto è "la persuasione d'esser sospettata e giudicata male" e il complemento oggetto è la "insidia". Se è così, penso che il significato della frase sia che la persuasione d'esser sospettata e giudicata male predisponeva o preparava Artemisia ad aspettarsi un'insidia.

Comment: Invece di "predisponere", si usa "predisporre". :)

Comment: @Benedetta: Grazie mille! Ho fatto la correzione.

Answer (score 0):

La presenza del complemento oggetto non è necessaria né obbligatoria. Se dico: "Ieri, mentre leggevo, mi ha telefonato un amico", sto usando il verbo "leggevo" all'imperfetto, il soggetto è "io", il complemento oggetto manca, ma l'azione del verbo è comprensibile.
Secondo me, nella frase "Per insidia che imbastisse la persuasione d'essere sospettata o giudicata male", "Per insidia che" è una congiunzione che introduce una costruzione di causa/ragione (per quale ragione Artemisia "non poté che rispecchiarsi innocente"?), mentre "imbastisse" è una forma passivante/impersonale senza il "si".

Comment: Non capisco come "per insidia che" possa essere una congiunzione causale. E con "forma passivante/impersonale" vuoi dire che dovrebbe essere "si imbastisse" invece di "imbastisse"?

Comment: Se "insidia" significa anche "pericolo, rischio", possiamo pensare che "per insidia che" significhi qualcosa come "Per paura che", "per timore che". "Si imbastisse", senza il "si".

Comment: E se "imbastire" è qui usato in modo impersonale, "la persuasione d'esser ..." sarebbe il complemento oggetto di questo verbo, no?